# "if" clause doesn't work into insert query in clickhouse

Tags: clickhouse

I'm trying to insert data from csv input.

Example of the row:

```
1627635473988516097,1627635479990773393,6002,3,0,1152,0,1627635479:0;,1,1,1,3,2,**46.216.7.214,128.140.255.27**,60561,500,0,0,0,0,0,0,191,0,0,375001000099,0,0,0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000,0,0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,116,0,0,['encrypted'],0,0,0,1545614606,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,206,0,0,0,0,0
```

This is part of INSERT query:

```sql
insert into migration.gate_clickstream_indexed (datetime, login, publicSrc, publicSrcV6, publicSrcPort, dst, dstV6, dstPort, bytesOut, bytesIn, application) 
select toDateTime(truncate(start_time/1E9)), toString(msisdn),a**ssumeNotNull(if (ip_src LIKE '%.%', IPv4StringToNum(ip_src), NULL)), assumeNotNull(if (ip_src LIKE '%:%', IPv6StringToNum(ip_src), NULL))**, port_src, assumeNotNull(if (ip_dst LIKE '%.%', IPv4StringToNum(ip_dst), NULL)), assumeNotNull(if (ip_dst LIKE '%:%', IPv6StringToNum(ip_dst), NULL)), port_dst, bytes_ul, bytes_dl, toString(application) 
from input
```

But in spite of "if" clause, ch inserts into publicSrcV6 formatted IPv4:

```
375001000099        0.0.0.0 ::  0   46.216.7.214    **::ffff:46.216.7.214** 60561   2021-07-30 11:57:53         128.140.255.27  **::ffff:128.140.255.27**   500 1152    0   0   2021-07-30
```

I'm not able to catch why?

Answer (score 0):

I've found out that this problem occurs only in case with IPv4 insertion.
I've tried use in "else" part instead of NULL this IPv4StringToNum('0.0.0.0').
And It works.